# I'm trying to insert to a set of a class

Tags: c++, stl, compilation, set, constants

I have 2 classes: Item and Customer, and I want to insert an item into the set of item (the set of items is in the customer).
The problem is that I want to change the count in the item and I have trouble with it because the iterator won't work with non-const functions such as setCount... so this doesn't compile:

```
void Customer::insertItem(Item *newItem)
{
    std::set<Item>::iterator it;
    if (newItem->getCount() == 0)
    {
        _items.insert(*newItem);
    }
    for (it = _items.begin(); it != _items.end(); it++)
    {
        if (_items.find(*newItem) != _items.end()&&it->getName()==newItem->getName())
        {
            it->setCount(it->getCount() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

but if i put const in the setCount it won't compile either because i cant change the value of count.

Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First off, why are you taking an argument as `Item *` and then inserting it into the set via copy-by-value?  If that's your intent, then take the argument as a `const Item &` instead.  If it's not your intent then you're likely leaking memory.

Secondly, it's not clear what problem you're seeing since this code doesn't actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please do not implement any work-around: The 'if' and 'for' are some.

Comment: @mbgda But I also need to change the count so it's not my problem...

Comment: @DieterLücking I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish here.  Why does the item need to know how many copies of it exist in the set?  Every time you add or remove a copy you're going to need to update the count of every remaining item with that same name.  If the data inside of Item is otherwise identical for all instances, when why not just update the count on the existing Item that's in the set instead of inserting a new instance each time and updating all of them?

Comment: That's what I'm doing..

Comment: That might be what you're trying to do, but it's not what you're actually doing due to the insertion by value.  I don't think the const is actually your issue here - it seems like you might not understand the difference between C++ pointers and C++ objects.

Comment: Without seeing the definition of Item and the code that's calling insertItem it's hard to know just how weird the behavior of this code is going to be.  But I can guarantee it not doing remotely what you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot call non-`const` methods on objects that you put in a `set`, as per §23.2.4/5-6 (in N3797, emphasis mine):

> (5) For `set` and `multiset` the value type is the same as the key type.
>
> (6) `iterator` of an associative container is of the bidirectional iterator category. For associative containers where the value type is the same as the key type, **both `iterator` and `const_iterator` are constant iterators.**

So when you try to do:

```
it->setCount(it->getCount() + 1);
```

That can't work, since the object `it` points to is `const`. If you still want to store the count internally to the object AND in a set, you can make whatever the count member variable is `mutable` and still mark `setCount()` to be `const`.

Far more likely though, the container you want is something like `std::map<std::string, Item>`, where your logic would be:

```
void Customer::insertItem(const Item& newItem)
{
    auto it = _items.find(newItem.getName());
    if (it == _items.end()) {
        // absent, insert it
        it = _items.insert(std::make_pair(newItem.getName(), newItem)).first;
    }

    // now increment the count
    // it->first is a const Key, but it->second is just Value, so it's mutable
    it->second.setCount(it->second.getCount() + 1);
}
```